# Java wait notify with two threads as same class

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a FileReader class which is like this

```
public class FileReader extends Thread
{

private final Object lock = new Object();

public FileReader(String path, FileReaderCallback callback)
{
    super(path);

    this.path = path;
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path)));
        String info;

        while ((info = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
                synchronized (lock)
                {
                    callback.onDone(path, info);

                    try
                    {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ignored)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void next()
{
    synchronized (lock)
    {
        try
        {
            lock.notify();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

And I have two instance of this FileReader because I want to read two file line by line simultaneously. The problem is my code only reads one line from both file and then it's going to pause.

I Call the function on my callback like this

```
public void onDone(String path, String info)
{
    reader1.next();
    reader2.next();
}
```

So what's the problem?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are your locks? How do you obtain them? Please include all your classes.

Comment: @ram I've edited my post. my lock is inside FileReader class but the onDone function is somewhere else (In my main class)

Comment: `lock.wait()` your running code is in that line, and you never show where you call `next()`

Comment: @nachokk I call lock.notify in my onDone callback. Why it doesn't continue after that?

Comment: @strings95 you call first onDone, and then you call `wait()`

Comment: @nachokk I'm checking in onDone whether both thread result are available and then call next() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lock` object which you synchronize the `next()` method to is also used within your `while` loop in the `run` method. Therefore, the code of your `next()` method cannot be called from within another thread.

Just assume the following program flow:

1. You start `reader1` thread
2. You start `reader2` thread

At some time one of those two threads start. Let's assume `reader1` thread starts first:

1. It syncs to its `lock` object
2. It reads a line from the file
3. It calls its callback, i.e. calls `next()` on `reader1` and `reader2`. This call is successful (but actually a no-op)
4. It calls `wait` on its `lock` object. And waits...

At some later time the `reader2` thread starts

1. It syncs to its `lock` object
2. It reads a line from the file
3. It calls its callback, however, when calling `reader1.next()` it tries to synchronize to the `reader1` its `lock` object from a different thread, thus putting your program into a deadlock state.

To solve this problem I would really suggest to overwork the concept of how you perform the line-by-line synchronization. An easy fix would probably be to use a different lock variable for your `next()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling listener call back while holding the lock on the same object `lock`. This will allow notify to be invoked before a wait is invoked. This will make your thread wait forever.

You should,

1. Use java.util.CountDownLatch for this problem.
2. Use ThreadPool. Extending from thread is old way of doing it and prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a classic deadlock scenario. Let the first lock be `lock1` and the second lock be `lock2`. In your first instance, the lock status can be expressed as follows:

```
synchronized (lock1) {
    // start of onDone
    synchronized (lock1) {

    }
    synchronized (lock2) {

    }
    // end of onDone
}
```

and in second one, it is like this:

```
synchronized (lock2) {
    // start of onDone
    synchronized (lock1) {

    }
    synchronized (lock2) {

    }
    // end of onDone
}
```

You should refine your logic, as other answers suggest.

Another flaw in your design is; you are also not considering possible spurious wakeups. Generally, you should put your `wait()` calls in a `while` loop.